# Does Visual Studio 2010 x86 installer work with 64 bits Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I got a installer for Visual Studio 2010 x86 from the msdn academic alliance, and I intalled on my computer with Windows 7 Home Premium and M460 i5 processor. It runs great, except it doesn't debug, neither C# nor C++.

If I build the project, and then press the debug button, it works. But why Debug button doesn't build automatically?

How can I make the debug button auto-compile and debug just clicking it, instead of first click build button and then click debug button?

**SOLUTION:** Oops, problem solved, it was just a silly thing ...

*Tools > Options> Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > On Run, When Projects Are Out Of Date > Always build*

**UPDATE:** Since the title is misleading, I think it is important to clarify that Visual Studio 2010 x86 (32 bits) installer works perfectly on amd64 (64 bits) machines. In fact,I think there is only x86 installer.

Comment: Please be more specific, "it doesn't debug" doesn't mean much.

Comment: @Chris The "debug" button doesn't create any file. The message "Cannot start debugging because the debug target ... is missing" pops up, the output directory is "bin\Debug\" and the platform target is "x86".

Answer (score 2):

My VS2010 Pro x86 that I acquired via our WebsiteSpark membership works fine on my Win7 Home Premium 64bit on an HP Pavilion w/AMD Turion II Ultra M620.

Could you elaborate on what you mean by "debug button doesn't do it automatically"? What exactly are you expecting to happen, and what exactly is happening?

Also, from what you say, debugging *does* work... just not when you try to do it via a certain process.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The "debug" button doesn't compile, it only runs the last version compiled by the "build" button. And when I haven't build the project, the next message appears: "Cannot start debugging because the debug target ... is missing". I have checked the output path and it looks correct: "bin\Debug\". Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine.  I'm running it now.  If you're having trouble installing, try right-clicking on the installer and selecting "Run as Adminstrator".

Answer (score 0):

not to familier with the software but have had simlar problem with similar programs.
if there is yet a 64x c# or c++ if so try install them it may just update the win7 binery files needed for the scripts to 64bit (or relivent files needed)
possibly a long shot put worth ago

hope it helps sorry for bad spelling